# eclipse E4\eclipse 3.6 debuging java script with rhino

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rhino

i am interested in the [E4 eclipse project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4) or eclipse 3.6 this platform offers few thinks that i really find interesting, like debugging javaScript with rhino.

unfortunately (but expected) i could not find any material about this platform (in case i succeed i would love to share the knowledge)

does anybody knows if the they have forum, group where i can ask questions and get answers?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web forum at [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=12&S=2ba2c83940523c3cadda5e76c523b7e1), which is really just a front end to the news groups (news://news.eclipse.org/eclipse.e4).

There is also a [development mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/e4-dev).